# selenium search for en element by multiple choice selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

*Is this syntax alright, if not what is the other way of getting en element which contains this or this or that?*

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Selling') or contains(text(), 'Buy') or contains(text(), 'Sales')]
```

Or is there any option like for example:

```
Find.Elements(By.LinkText("this" or "this" or "that"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining multiple `contains()` conditions is perfectly fine and valid. You may use `.` in place of `text()` to save <strike>water and planet</strike> some space:

```
//*[contains(., 'Selling') or contains(., 'Buy') or contains(., 'Sales')]
```

---

Alternatively, you may try using the "link text" locator multiple times handling exceptions:

```
string[] texts = {"Selling", "Buy", "Sales"};
for(int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++)
{
    try
    {
        return driver.FindElement(by.LinkText(texts[i]));
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        continue;
    }
}
throw new NoSuchElementException();
```

<sup>My C# skills are quite rusty (forgive mistakes).</sup>